# Continuum in an open interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b.$ Then the open interval $(a, b)$ has cardinality of the continuum.

The proof of $f:(0,1) \to (a,b)$ defined by $f(x) := (b-a)x+a$ is given.

Can somebody explain why this function is chosen to represent $(a,b)?$

Comment: To "represent"?

Comment: Ok, why every point in (0,1) is mapped to a point in (a,b)

Comment: That is, why if $0<x<1$, then $a<(b-a)x+a<b$?

Comment: @user127700 ... your question "why is every point in (0,1) mapped to a point in (a,b)" is the same as asking, "Why is $f(0) \le f(x) \le f(1)$ for every $x\in (0,1)$.  This is easy to prove,first we know that $a<b$ and that $0 < 1$ so we just have to show that this is an increasing function on $(0,1)$.  This is because $b$ and $(b-a)$ are fixed and so the only thing that changes is $x$ which is increasing on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons.......  its linear with respect to $x$ (so its easy to work with) more importantly its a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $(0,1)$ and its assumed that you have already proven $(0,1)$ has the cardinality of the continuum.

So if there is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and they have the same cardinality and $(0,1)$ and $(a,b)$ have a bijection, then by composing the bijections we have a bijection between any $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

To see that it is a bijection is easy:

Its one-one:  Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ then $(b-a)x+a = (b-a)y+a$ shows that $x=y$.

Its onto: For any $y\in (a,b)$ we can find $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$; just plug in for $x=\frac{y-a}{b-a}$ you'll see this does the job.
Because it is 1-1 and onto... it is bijective.